# Link Visual Basic with Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, call

i've been searching about how to link visual basic with python file

i've tried so hard through  using `shell` in Visual Basic but nothing happend

i have python file called `Go.py` and i want to link Visual Basic button with it and get the return into variable

any idea ?

Comment: You're using IronPython, right?

Comment: That would be your problem. VB.net targets the CLR, as does IronPython.

Comment: i'll install ironPython but how could i link the Visual Basic with it?

Comment: What are you passing in for your `shell` arguments? You may need to target the absolute filepath of the python (or pythonw) exe, as well as the script you're attempting to execute.

Comment: Go read the IronPython documentation. Do not ask questions on stackoverflow until you have done a reasonable amount of research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you *can* use `Shell`, although it's unfortunately probably more complicated than you imagined.

Your current problem is a simple one - `Shell` can't run a python file directly, so you need to have `Shell` call `cmd /c python.exe Go.py`, and you may need to provide a full path to `python.exe` as well.

However, you also want to capture the result, and `Shell` only returns the process ID, not any kind of process output.  You can check out some [examples of external process invocation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic/External_Processes), although they don't explicitly cover how to capture output.  If `Go.py` outputs to the terminal, you can probably capture the output into a file using [standard Windows output redirection](http://blog.crankybit.com/redirecting-output-to-a-file-in-windows-batch-scripts/), and then open the file in VisualBasic and read the values.

You can also use [`System.Diagnostics.Process()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx#Y0) instead of jumping through all the hoops of trying to get more functionality out of `Shell`.  (Specifically, review the [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) class properties related to output redirection which give you much more control than anything using `Shell` will).

Comment: i thought it's easy like python to get result via   "os.popen("cc.py").read()"

Comment: @EngHamoud: Sadly that's not really the case - also, even in Python you should be using the `subprocess` module, whose `Popen` class functions very much like the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class in VB.