# Opening Python files via Visual Basic 2010

Tags: c#, python, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to make a Visual Basic 2010 program that can open a Python file. I've tried doing,

```
Shell("C:\Users\Seth Connell\Desktop\J.A.R.V.I.S\Jarvis.py")
```

but it returns an Error, "FileNotFound Exception Was Unhandled", but I know the file is at that location. Am I doing something wrong? Can Visual Basic 2010 open python files?

Comment: look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350899/link-visual-basic-with-python) if it helps

Comment: Ok thanks, but I've already found a quick solution.

Comment: good to know mind sharing it

Comment: they same thing i had in mind

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Users\Seth Connell\Desktop\J.A.R.V.I.S\Jarvis.py")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a great alternative to Shell(), it's System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(). It's relatively the same thing.

So the solution is,

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Users\Seth Connell\Desktop\J.A.R.V.I.S\Jarvis.py")
```